# Webencore Fails : Duplicate plugin/preset detected

Tags: reactjs, symfony, babeljs

I am trying to use React with Symfony 4 but i couldn't achieve. 
When i try to build webpack i got the following error for every .js file that i added to webpack.config.js via .addEntry()

```
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
Error: Duplicate plugin/preset detected.
If you'd like to use two separate instances of a plugin,
they need separate names, e.g.

  plugins: [
    ['some-plugin', {}],
    ['some-plugin', {}, 'some unique name'],
  ]
    at assertNoDuplicates (/var/www/admin.whenandwhere.events/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-descriptors.js:205:13)
    at createDescriptors (/var/www/admin.whenandwhere.events/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-descriptors.js:114:3)
    at createPresetDescriptors (/var/www/admin.whenandwhere.events/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-descriptors.js:101:10)
    at passPerPreset (/var/www/admin.whenandwhere.events/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-descriptors.js:58:96)
    at cachedFunction (/var/www/admin.whenandwhere.events/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/caching.js:33:19)
    at presets.presets (/var/www/admin.whenandwhere.events/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-descriptors.js:29:84)
    at mergeChainOpts (/var/www/admin.whenandwhere.events/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-chain.js:320:26)
    at /var/www/admin.whenandwhere.events/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-chain.js:283:7
    at buildRootChain (/var/www/admin.whenandwhere.events/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-chain.js:68:29)
    at loadPrivatePartialConfig (/var/www/admin.whenandwhere.events/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/partial.js:85:55)
    at Object.loadPartialConfig (/var/www/admin.whenandwhere.events/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/partial.js:110:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/admin.whenandwhere.events/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js:140:26)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (/var/www/admin.whenandwhere.events/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js:3:103)
    at _next (/var/www/admin.whenandwhere.events/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js:5:194)
    at /var/www/admin.whenandwhere.events/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js:5:364
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/admin.whenandwhere.events/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js:5:97)
    at Object._loader (/var/www/admin.whenandwhere.events/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js:220:18)
    at Object.loader (/var/www/admin.whenandwhere.events/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js:56:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/admin.whenandwhere.events/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js:51:12)
```

But i didn't specify any plugin neither .babelrc or webpack.config.js.
Here are my files

**webpack.config.js**

```
var Encore = require('@symfony/webpack-encore');

Encore
    .setOutputPath('public/build/')
    .setPublicPath('/build')
    .addEntry('app', './assets/js/main.js')
    .addStyleEntry('global', './assets/css/global.scss')
    .splitEntryChunks()
    .enableSingleRuntimeChunk()
    .cleanupOutputBeforeBuild()
     .enableSassLoader()
    .autoProvidejQuery() 
    .enableBuildNotifications()
    .enableSourceMaps(!Encore.isProduction())
    .enableVersioning(Encore.isProduction())
    .enableReactPreset()
    .configureBabel((config) => {
    config.presets.push(
      ['@babel/env'],
      ['@babel/react'],

    )})
    .addEntry('react', './assets/js/reactGeoSuggest.js')
;

module.exports = Encore.getWebpackConfig();
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "@symfony/webpack-encore": "^0.23.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.4.1",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.11.0",
    "popper.js": "^1.14.7",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "webpack-notifier": "^1.6.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.3.4",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.5",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^16.8.4",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.4"
  }
}
```

I don't have any **.babelrc** file.

So it looks very strange for me getting this error, i tried to follow a few tutorials but they were outdated due to babel 7 changes. Now i am stuck at this error.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `.enableReactPreset()` or `config.presets.push(['@babel/env'], ['@babel/react'])})`

These basicly do the same thing, if no .babelrc file is present.

Comment: Actually if i remove .enableReactPreset() i got the same error but if i remove . configureBabel() i got syntax error : Unexpected token, expected "{" (11:11)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your configuration is conflicted each other. As long as, you would like to use Encore and Symfony with React, you're supposed to watch this tutorial.

https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/webpack-encore

In addition, If you prefer to go ahead with this, you should run this command add that file.

`npm install -D @babel/core @babel/preset-env babel-loader`

.babelrc

`{
     "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"]
 }`

Comment: No i don't think this is the point. .babelrc is not mandatory and you can configure at webpack.config.js

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when I try to run a react project. I have fixed the issue by modifying the package.json file.
Simple solution: just delete the "^" in "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0", from your package.json file, And run the npm install command after npm cache verify.

Answer (score 0):

Your **webpack.config.js** contains **babel/env**. But there is not any package with same name in npm repository. There is **babel-preset-env**. This package webpack encore includes by default - according to Symfony documentation "Configuring Babel"
https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/babel.html

> Babel is automatically configured for all .js and .jsx files via the
>   babel-loader with sensible defaults (e.g. with the @babel/preset-env
>   and @babel/preset-react if requested).

So try change your config to this:

```
.enableReactPreset()
.configureBabel(function(babelConfig) {

}, {

});
```

You don't need add '@babel/react' as preset in webpack config 
because option .enableReactPreset() already has been doing this https://github.com/symfony/webpack-encore/blob/v0.27.0/lib/loaders/babel.js#L57-L61

If you need enable additional presets or plugins use this syntax according Symfony Documentation "Configuring Babel"

Also your package.json is redundant. You can remove from its:

- @babel/preset-react
- @babel/preset-env
- babel-loader
  redundant
  These packages has been already included as dependency for **@symfony/webpack-encore**

See here https://github.com/symfony/webpack-encore/blob/v0.27.0/package.json